# How to fetch specific data from string using regex in python

Tags: regex

**I have following program in  in that  want to fetch**

**"planned", "not automated", "st3reporter", "functional", "report-upto3times-per2hrs", "st3-throttling-cdb"**

**These value from string **

```
import re
string='''
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ReportUpToTimesEveryHours {

        String objective = "04 - Report up to 3 times every 2 hours";
        String testName = "ReportUpToTimesEveryHours";

@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void beforeMethod() {
        logger.info(Constants.LOGGER_SEPERATOR);
        logger.info("Start -- " + testName + " - " + objective);

}

                        @Test(groups = { "planned", "not automated", "st3reporter", "functional", "report-upto3times-per2hrs", "st3-throttling-cdb" },
        description = "04 - Report up to 3 times every 2 hours")
public void testReportUpToTimesEveryHours() {

}

@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void afterMethod() {
        logger.info("End -- " + testName + " - " + objective);
        logger.info(Constants.LOGGER_SEPERATOR);
}

}
'''
pattern=re.compile(r' (\@Test\(groups\s*=\s*\{)')
m= pattern.search(string)
print m.group()
```

Comment: What do you want us to do? Read your program?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, or what your question is. You're parsing a Java program with regex in Python? Why? And what does that have to do with Django, which is a web framework?

Comment: question has nothing to do with Django, have removed the tag and edited the title for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
pattern=re.compile(r' @Test\(groups\s*=\s*\{([^\}]+)')
result_set = [i.strip() for i in 
              pattern.search(string).group(1).replace('"', '').split(',')]
```

The value will store a list:

```
['planned', 'not automated', 'st3reporter', 'functional', 'report-upto3times-per2hrs', 'st3-throttling-cdb']
```

Comment: ['planned', 'not automated', 'st3reporter', 'functional', 'report-upto3times-per2hrs', 'st3-throttling-cdb']

How to remove the double coat from result_set string like above

Comment: Answer updated.. just use replace method over group @user3647087